# how to remove index column when export file in R

Tags: r

I am using R programming to export a .dat file. but the exported file is always included the index column. Is there any possible way/ code to export data in R without index column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say you are using write.table and your dataset is df then following will work for you

```
write.table(df,'df.dat',row.names=F)
```

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you very much. But how can I remove the V1 on the top of the culumn?

Comment: For this specific answer provide sample of your data... I don't know what is v1 indicates in your case

Comment: It is likely to be the title of the column when i am exporting with .dat. In case, I export with .csv, it didn't show up. ex: V1 0 0 0 0 1 2 5

Comment: if you don't want column names as well then try this, `write.table(df,'df.dat',row.names=F,col.names=F)` If this one helps you let me know.. I will edit answer as well